# Flutter firebase create user without firebase auth

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I get the otp code from another service that is cheaper in my country, so I don't use firebase auth.I want to use firebase auth. I also want to use the OTP service I bought from outside.

I am using the phone number because it is Uniqe as my id. Is there any harm in this process?

```
-users
  --userId(phone number)
   -name
   -lastname
```

Since there are 200 people registered in the system, I want to handle the previous users without making mistakes.

Comment: "I want to perform firebase auth transaction with OTP code" Can you clarify what you mean there? How is Firebase involved in this transaction?

Comment: you cannot get the OTP from one provider and use Auth from another. (Because technically the code has to be verified on both ends: sent and received) .... Not sure how you will use firebase auth without its phoneNumber option :)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the clarifications Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry i explained wrong. I want to use firebase auth. I also want to use the OTP service I bought from outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the sign-in flow with an external provider, you can [create a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) with the Firebase Admin SDK to make that user available within Firebase.